# My software rec question got closed as a duplicate, while it is not

Tags: discussion

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/319433/windows-proccess-explorer-like-tray-utility-lightweight) got closed. As a duplicate.
However, I asked if there is an equivalent to "Proccess Explorer". Not a CPU monitor. Proccesss Explorer does MUCH more. Memory usage, network usage, commit history, I/O, disk usage. AND CPU usage.

How can I get the question open again?

Comment: By asking it here, you are contesting it to be opened again. You may want to edit this post a little more clearly to define why it should be opened again

Comment: Normally, the term "lightweight" doesn't go alongside with a million features and monitors like you want in a "simple tray monitor".  Just remember, it takes CPU cycles to actually figure out those things, they aren't "just available".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I agree that they kind of mismatch. Seems the moderator didn't read your full question...

But, reconsider your question first before asking for it to be reopened, because it's too localized:

**Why won't you find any answers?**

Process Explorer is a highly specialized tool written by Sysinternals, which is part of Microsoft. You won't find any other program that will display all the different features you mention in tray graphs, other than Process Hacker there are no tools that even come close to the data that Sysinternals provides.

**Why can't you find any lightweight answers?**

Calculating the values itself are costly by itself; tracing CPU and I/O cycles, summing up Memory, ...
Adding a graph will make it even more heavy weight, it's not lightweight by it's intrinsic nature.

**Why shouldn't you care about these statistics in general?**

There's nothing wrong with your CPU, GPU or I/O being 100% for an extended duration; to give you an example, during a 30 minutes Torture Test (stressed *all* components) I ran today I could still browse around Super User. The only thing that I did notice was *slowness*, or better said *less responsiveness*.

It's this last visual cue that you see that you should use to determine when you need to actually take a look at what your computer is actually doing, as that's the only moment you should give attention to it. That's actually the only moment that program should be using your *costly idle CPU cycles*.

Yes, responsiveness works both ways. The more idle CPU cycles and context switches you have, the less responsive your PC will become. You know that effect where after some months your PC becomes slower and slower? That's because the amount of idle CPU cycles and context switches has increased to that point, and it's because all kind of tiny changes to your system of which the performance has never been analyzed. Yes, adding entries to your hosts file causes some periodically extra idle CPU cycles!

As for memory usage, you should rather have bought enough memory as well have a page file to back you up; at this point, you will again get to see *slowness* when your computer starts disk trashing because your memory ran too full. Here, it's again not necessary to keep your eyes on the monitor. There is also no reason to keep your memory usage low, because *free memory is simply wasted memory*....

So, would you want to keep your eye on your screen corner or would you want to use your computer?

**Why are these graphs available?**

For *active* monitoring purposes, where the change in one of the graphs is important to be monitored. IT admins, Developers and Server administrators sometimes need to watch these while performing certain tasks, but in the general Super User case they aren't necessary to be watched as there is no benefit from the cost these graphs take from you...

**But, I really want them?**

We can't search the deepest corners of the internet for you, people will most likely close your question again for being too localized. So, you could attempt to write such a solution yourself, or keep looking...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)